# How many DNA sequences of length $3$ that have no C's at all or have no T's in the first position?

Tags: combinatorics

How many DNA sequences of length $3$ that have no C's at all or have no T's in the first position?

Here are my workings below but I am not sure if they are correct or not,

So there are $4$ letters of the DNA sequence, CTGA

So considering DNA sequences of length $3$ that have no C's at all,

the first position can be filled by $3$ options, the second by $3$ options and the last by $3$ options, so therefore $3\times3\times3=27$

Considering DNA sequences of length $3$ that have no T's in the first position,

the first position can be filled by $3$ options, the second by $4$ options and the last by $4$ options, so therefore $3\times4\times4= 48$

So combining both cases, there are $48+27$ DNA sequences.

Comment: You counted AGG (among others) twice.

Comment: Not quite. You've counted some sequences twice. Count those and subtract.

Comment: @EthanBolker okay so for my first option I will remain with 27 but then for the second it seems that when G A C are in the first slot, there are only 7 new sequences for each letter, so therefore 27+7+7+7?

Comment: @eyeballfrog does my comment above make sense?

Comment: Not quite. *Every* sequence with C as the first letter is new, because in the initial 27 you excluded *all* sequences with Cs.

Comment: @eyeballfrog so then it should be 7+7 from A and G but 48 from C, so 27+7+7+48?

Comment: @eyeballfrog so it should be 16 new ones from C then

Comment: Yeah. There's also an easier way to do this which I might as well post as the answer.

Comment: @eyeballfrog yeah that would be great, I'm here trying to write them all out haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using the inclusion-exclusion principle. If you want to find the number of things that are X or Y, you add the number of Xs to the number of Ys, then subtract the number of things that are both X and Y, since they were counted twice.

- There are $3\times3\times3 = 27$ sequences have no Cs.
- There are $3\times4\times4 = 48$ sequences that don't begin with T.
- There are $2\times3\times3 = 18$ sequences that don't begin with T and have no Cs.

So the total number is $27 + 48 - 18 = 57$.

As an alternate method, you could also count the number that have a T in the first position and at least one C (i.e., the ones that *aren't* in your solution set). There are 7 of these. Since there are 64 possible sequences, that means the number that *are* in your solution set is $64 - 7 = 57$, which agrees with the above.

Comment: thanks so much!